# Distinguish between SendMessage & Keypress

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage, postmessage

I'm not sure if it's possible, if not then please don't flame me :) I'm noobie yet.

I would like to filter keyboard event's coming from SendMessage or PostMessage, and deny them. I'm working in VS2013 C++ (Win8.1).

Could you give me a point where I could start at?
Thank you.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Actually real key presses arrive via neither. The closest API to a real keypress is `SendInput`.

Comment: Why do you ask the question? What about `SendInput` or `keybd_input`?

Comment: The difference between `[Send|Post]Message` and input generated from a keyboard driver is the state at the time of arrival: If you build your own (unmaintainably complex) state machine based on information gathered from [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx) you should be able to distinguish between input that is the result of a `[Send|Post]Message` and input from other sources.

Comment: So, all in one: No :) Damn, okay :/

Comment: You *might* be able to filter based on the values in the `lparam`. Some programs that call `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` to simulate keys won't set all the bits correctly. But if they are set correctly then you don't know the difference. In general, the answer to your question is that it's possible but really, really difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's hardly possible at all. Thank you, question answered.